# Erlang record to tuple list

Tags: erlang, records

I'm trying to work out a macro definition that will turn a record into a tuple list. Something like:

```
> Id = #id{id1=1,id2=2,id3=3}.
{id,1,2,3}
> ?record_to_tuplelist(id,Id).
[{id1,1},{id2,2},{id3,3}]
```

So far I worked out this:

```
-define(record_to_tuplelist(Rec,RecRef), [ {X,RecRef#Rec.X} || X <- record_info(fields,Rec) ]).
```

But it gives a syntax error. If I change RecRef#Rec.X to RecRef#Rec{} it works, but doesn't return what I want. Is this just an obscure syntax error or is this actually not possible?

Comment: you should learn how to [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873532/how-do-i-turn-a-list-of-tuple-pairs-into-a-record-in-erlang)

Comment: That's a tuple pair list into a record, I want to do the opposite. That answer is where I got the basis for my current attempt. You should learn to not be hostile, especially when you're wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, both the record name and the field names have to be atoms. How about something like (untested):

```
-define(record_to_tuplelist(Rec, Ref), lists:zip(record_info(fields, Rec),tl(tuple_to_list(Ref)))).
```